# How can I fix crashed Cinnamon?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, windows, cinnamon, parallels

I get an error after logining to computer. It returns the message **Cinnamon just crashed. You are currently running in fallback mode. Do you want to restart Cinnamon?** I selected **Yes**, but it had still returned again popup and want to me select yes or no restart.

This is my system informations:

```
➜  ~ inxi -Fxz
System:    Host: anchu-mint Kernel: 4.15.0-124-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.5.0
           Desktop: Cinnamon 3.8.9 (Gtk 3.22.30) Distro: Linux Mint 19 Tara
Machine:   Device: desktop Mobo: MSI model: H81M-P33 (MS-7817) v: 1.0 serial: N/A
           BIOS: American Megatrends v: V1.7 date: 07/18/2014
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i3-4150 (-MT-MCP-) arch: Haswell rev.3 cache: 3072 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 13999
           clock speeds: max: 3500 MHz 1: 1357 MHz 2: 1129 MHz 3: 1152 MHz 4: 1161 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2)
           version: 4.5 Mesa 20.0.8 Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-124-generic
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: e000 bus-ID: 02:00.0
           IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Realtek RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
           driver: r8188eu v: v4.1.4_6773.20130222 usb-ID: 003-003
           IF: wlxc46e1f1ef189 state: N/A mac: N/A
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 250.1GB (38.1% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST250DM000 size: 250.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 28G used: 25G (94%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda8
           ID-2: /boot size: 453M used: 431M (100%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda7
           ID-3: /home size: 69G used: 61G (93%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda9
           ID-4: swap-1 size: 4.00GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda6
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8C mobo: 27.8C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 229 Uptime: 2:25 Memory: 3133.3/15919.2MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 7.5.0
           Client: Shell (fish) inxi: 2.3.56
```

My Linux desktop runs parallel Windows 7. I found some solutions to fix errors, examples: restart computer, or re-install Cinnamon (`sudo apt-get install --reinstall cinnamon cinnamon-screensaver  cinnamon-session  cinnamon-session-common cinnamon-settings-daemon  libcinnamon-control-center1  libcinnamon-menu-3-0   mint-meta-cinnamon`),... but not working.

What do I have to do? Is there any solutions that do not recovery system or I do not need to delete all data?

If you want to know anything, do not hesitate to ask me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Comment:-
You may soon get a future problem - You are (probably) using too much space in / `size: 28G used: 25G (94%)` - it is likely that you have an excessive number of kernels installed.

You have not lost any data and you do not need to reinstall Cinnamon. I would expect that it comes down to your video card.

Even when Cinnamon has crashed, your computer is still running.